# How can I remove special characters in a PHP string?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am getting output as

```
FBI believed he had a â€˜doomsday deviceâ€™
```

instead of

```
FBI believed he had a ‘doomsday device’
```

when i am using

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $topic);
```

output is

```
FBI believed he had a âdoomsday deviceâ
```

I am not using any header or charset in my file.

**Update**

Got why is this happening

when the UTF-8 series of numbers is interpreted as if it were ISO-8859-1 the output is

â€™

**Explaination**

0xE28099 breaks down as 0xE2 (â), 0x80 (€) and 0x99 (™). What was one character in UTF-8 (’) gets mistakenly displayed as three (â€™) when misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1.

Still no solution to convert it

Comment: Why not fix the root of the problem instead? See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: Are these string coming from a mysql database? try running this before running the select queries : `SET NAMES 'UTF-8'`

Comment: yes these are coming from mysql database. setting to utf8 using procedural style prints blank no data is displayed

Comment: @Pekka the output I am getting, what type of encoding is that?

Comment: It's probably UTF-8 shown in a single-byte encoding like ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Should probably be noted that browsers don't really support ISO-8859-1 and that characters like `€`, `’` and `‘` are unrepresentable in ISO-8859-1. There is no reason to use ISO-8859-1 over Windows-1252 ever (in this context :P I'm sure it has uses because all the 256 characters are first 256 characters in unicode as well) because it just has useless control characters in place of characters like `€`

Answer (score 2):

Well the output page is being interpreted in `Windows-1252`, not ISO-8859-1..

I recommend setting your header charset to utf-8:

In apache config:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Php.ini:

```
default_charset utf-8
```

Manually in php:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

If you cannot do anything of the above because of some weird reasons, you should then convert into Windows-1252 instead:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252//IGNORE", $topic);
```

Comment: when I did iconv one the third option which is in my question is displayed

Comment: @NavneetPandey read carefully, my iconv is *different* from  yours. *Your* iconv has *ISO-8859-1*, mine has *Windows-1252*.

Comment: @NavneetPandey You are leaving something out then. You should show full code regarding this.